# What does Enurement mean in a contract?

Tags: contract-law

Example:

> Enurement: This Agreement will enure to the benefit of and be binding
>   on the Parties and their respective heirs, executors, administrators
>   and permitted successors and assigns.

I do not get what any of this means. Can someone give a simple example when this may come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does Enurement mean in a contract?

Black's Law Dictionary defines *enure* as "*To operate or take effect. To serve to the use, benefit, or advantage of a person*".

The clause in your contract means that both entitlements and duties as provided in the agreement affect the parties but may be transfered to their heirs, successors, etc. In other words, that the death of a party does not extinguish the provisions in the contract.

Comment: "In other words, that the death of a party does not extinguish the provisions in the contract." how would this work? If they never agreed to the contract they can't be forced into it. Or is the idea the successor is given the option to accept? What type of contracts is Enurement provisions common in, employment contracts?

Comment: @somename1 I don't know where enurement provisions are common, nor to what extent they would be enforceable in an employment contract that may even be unbeknownst to third parties. Having more context would have been helpful. But, generally speaking, successors/heirs/executors/etc. are not allowed to *selectively* decide which entitlements & duties they accept.

Comment: Uhm I wonder: is that clause useless? I mean: heirs can obviously refused to get the inheritance and they wouldn't be bound by any agreement signed by their parents/other relatives. So this clause can be enacted only when they do accept inheritance... but at that point I'd thought that any contracts pertaining with the objects inherited would automatically be passed on... I mean if my parents get a car via lease and they die I don't simply take the car with me and stop paying the lease... So what does this clause do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Remember there are usually two parties to an employment contract, an employer and employee. An enurement clause in the contract also protects the employee if their employer merges with another entity, a corporation winds up, etc.